# my program erase the first calculation and just put the last calculation into the array

Tags: android, arrays

I'm trying to calculate shortest path between user location to two destinations
and put the distance value into an array.

instead put all the calculation into the array, the result that i get in the array is only the distance from second destination. apparently my program erase the first calculation and after that start the next calculation. What should i correct so that my program does not erase the first calculation and put all the distance into the array ?

it should be like this :

1. distance1= distance from user locationA to LocationH
2. distance2= distance from user locationA to LocationI
3. add distance to distanArray
4. The result is distanArray=(distance1,distance2)

what i have now :

distanArray=(distance2)

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

TextView tvDistanceDuration;
TextView tvDistanceDuration2;
TextView tvDistanceDuration3;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calcdistance);

    tvDistanceDuration = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tvDistanceDuration2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tvDistanceDuration3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
       } 
    else {

              Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                        "Location not available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the location listener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
     }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lon = (double) (location.getLongitude());

    Location locationA = new Location("USER");  
    locationA.setLatitude(lat);  
    locationA.setLongitude(lon);

    List<LatLng> pointss = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    List<LatLng> pointsss = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    Location locationH = new Location("Shelter 7");  
    locationH.setLatitude(-0.868101);  
    locationH.setLongitude(119.888341);

    Location locationI = new Location("Shelter 8");  
    locationI.setLatitude(-0.900198);  
    locationI.setLongitude(119.88856);

    LatLng des = new LatLng(locationA.getLatitude(), locationA.getLongitude());
    LatLng des1 = new LatLng(locationH.getLatitude(), locationH.getLongitude());                    
    LatLng des2 = new LatLng(locationI.getLatitude(), locationI.getLongitude());

    pointss.add(des1);
    pointss.add(des2);
    pointsss.add(des);
    tvDistanceDuration3.setText(String.valueOf(pointss));

    for (int i = 0; i <(pointss.size()); i++) { 
        LatLng origin = pointsss.get(0);
        LatLng dest = pointss.get(i);

        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
    downloadTask.execute(url);
}
}

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }



    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";
            ArrayList<String> distan = new ArrayList<String>();


            if(result.size()<1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 

                    if(j==0){   // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                        distan.add(distance);
                        continue;
                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                    points.add(position);   

                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);


            }

            String minDist = Collections.min(distan);
            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+minDist + ", Duration:"+duration);
            tvDistanceDuration2.setText(String.valueOf(distan));
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   


}
```

Comment: Are you saying that your `locationA` is removed ?

Comment: As i can see in your code you are only adding the two values in your `List<LatLng> pointsss` array and one value in your `List<LatLng> pointss` So you will get always the two values from `pointss` and one value from `pointsss`.

Comment: Best thing is to learn how to use the debugger and step through your code.

Comment: the one that removed is only distance1..my distanArray should be =(distance1,distance2).but my program gave distanArray = (distance2) instead. I think my program removed distance1 before calculate distance2. @GrlsHu